# c++ cgi app calling other program fails

Tags: c++, cgi, system-calls

I develop a c++ CGI program that runs under Windows and Linux.

This program calls another program like this:

```
system("otherProgram.exe arguments");
```

I also tried:

```
spawnl(_P_WAIT, "otherProgram.exe", "argument1", NULL);
```

This works fine in my debugger and in my Virtual Machine, but on my test server it doesn't work.
The system call returns -1.

Any ideas why?

Comment: what is the value of `errno`? (look [here](http://www.barricane.com/c-error-codes-include-errno) for possible values)

Comment: thanks for this tipp. errno is returning 13: permission denied. i don't know why but that's at least a hint.

Comment: can you check what are the read/execute/ etc. rights on that program on the server? and under which account does your CGI program run? might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a permissions issue. By default your CGI application will be run as if by user nobody. The program you want to launch should be executable by "nobody".

Comment: the folder that contains my applications grants all permissions to everyone

Comment: I had to grant rights to `cmd.exe` for user `Everyone` and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Is the directory containing "otherProgram.exe" in one of the directories in your PATH environment variable in the test box? That is, does your operating system know how to find that program?

Comment: i check if the program exists first and and it does but i cant execute it. i tried console commands as well and they don't work. like "md testFolder"

Comment: You may also consider trying executing a shell command that does not require file permissions or rely on a certain path to rule out environmental problems. "echo 'Hello World'" or something, as an example. If that fails, then your web server may not be granting you permissions to run the system() call, maybe?

Comment: echo hello doesn't work either. i will ask my admin if he knows why